# PyQt5 - Properly dynamically sizing and laying out components

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I am trying to make a GUI that will display (and eventually let the user build) circuits. Below is a rough sketch of what the application is supposed to look like.

[image: Sketch of application]

The bottom panel (currently a simple `QToolBar`) should be of constant height but span the width of the application and the side panels (`IOPanel`s in the below code) should have a constant width and span the height of the application.

The main part of the application (`Canvas`, which is currently a `QWidget` with an overriden `paintEvent` method, but might eventually become a `QGraphicsScene` with a `QGraphicsView` or at least something scrollable) should then fill the remaining space.

This is my current code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self._wire_ys = None
        self._init_ui()
        self.update_wire_ys()

    def update_wire_ys(self):
        self._wire_ys = [(i + 0.5) * self.panel.height() / 4 for i in range(4)]
        self.input.update_field_positions()
        self.output.update_field_positions()

    def wire_ys(self):
        return self._wire_ys

    def _init_ui(self):
        self.panel = QWidget(self)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, self.panel)
        self.input = IOPanel(self, self.panel)
        self.output = IOPanel(self, self.panel)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self.panel)
        hbox.addWidget(self.canvas, 1, Qt.AlignCenter)
        hbox.addWidget(self.input, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        hbox.addWidget(self.output, 0, Qt.AlignRight)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.panel)
        self.addToolBar(Qt.BottomToolBarArea, self._create_run_panel())
        self.reset_placement()

    def _create_run_panel(self):
        # some other code to create the toolbar
        return QToolBar(self)

    def reset_placement(self):
        g = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()
        self.resize(0.4 * g.width(), 0.4 * g.height())
        self.move(g.center().x() - self.width() / 2, g.center().y() - self.height() / 2)

    def resizeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().resizeEvent(*args, **kwargs)
        self.update_wire_ys()


class IOPanel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, main_window, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.main = main_window
        self.io = [Field(self) for _ in range(4)]

    def update_field_positions(self):
        wire_ys = self.main.wire_ys()
        for i in range(len(wire_ys)):
            field = self.io[i]
            field.move(self.width() - field.width() - 10, wire_ys[i] - field.height() / 2)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(40, self.main.height())


class Field(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setText(str(0))
        self.resize(20, 20)


# This class is actually defined in another module and imported
class Canvas(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, main_window, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.main = main_window

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        print("ASFD")
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self._draw(qp)
        qp.end()

    def _draw(self, qp):
        # Draw stuff
        qp.drawLine(0, 0, 1, 1)


# __main__.py
def main():
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running that code gives me the following:

[image: Result]

Here I have coloured the components to better see them using code like this in their construction:

```
p = self.palette()
p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), Qt.blue)
self.setPalette(p)
self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
```

Green is the central panel (`MainWindow.panel`), blue are the `IOPanel`s, the `Field`s are supposed to be red, and the `Canvas` is supposed to be white.

Ignore the bottom toolbar, it's some extra code I didn't include above (to keep it as minimal and relevant as possible), but it does no resizing of anything and no layout management except for its own child `QWidget`. In fact, including the painting code in my above minimal example gave a similar result with thinner bottom toolbar without the Run button. I'm just including the toolbar here to show its expected behaviour (as the toolbar is working correctly) in the general layout.

This result has several problems.

## Problem 1

The `Field`s do not show up, initially. *However*, they do show up (and are appropriately placed within their respective panels) once I resize the main window. Why is this? The only thing the main window's `resizeEvent` does is `update_wire_ys` and `update_field_positions`, and those are performed by the main window's `__init__` as well.

## Problem 2

The `IOPanel`s are not properly aligned. The first one should be on the left side of the central panel. Changing the order of adding them fixes this, as so:

```
hbox.addWidget(self.input, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
hbox.addWidget(self.canvas, 1, Qt.AlignCenter)
hbox.addWidget(self.output, 0, Qt.AlignRight)
```

However, shouldn't the `Qt.AlignX` already do this, regardless of the order they're added in? What if I later on wanted to add another panel to the left side, would I have to remove all the components, add the new panel and then re-add them?

## Problem 3

The `IOPanel`s are not properly sized. They need to span the entire height of the central panel and touch the left/right edge of the central panel. I'm not sure if this is an issue with the layout or my colouring of the panels. What am I doing wrong?

## Problem 4

The `Canvas` does not show up at all and in fact its `paintEvent` is never called ("ASFD" never gets printed to the console). I have not overridden its `sizeHint`, because I want the central panel's layout to appropriately size the `Canvas` by itself. I was hoping the stretch factor of 1 when adding the component would accomplish that.

```
hbox.addWidget(self.canvas, 1, Qt.AlignCenter)
```

How do I get the canvas to actually show up and fill all the remaining space on the central panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the typical spaghetti code, where many elements are tangled, which is usually difficult to test, I have found many problems such as `sizeEvent` is only called when the layout containing the widget is called, another example is when you use the Function `update_field_positions` and `update_wire_ys` that handle each other object.

In this answer I will propose a simpler implementation:

- `IOPanel` clas must contain a `QVBoxLayout` that handles the changes of image size.
- In the `MainWindow` class we will use the layouts with the alignments but you must add them in order.

  ```
  lay.addWidget(self.input, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
  lay.addWidget(self.canvas, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
  lay.addWidget(self.output, 0, Qt.AlignRight)
  ```
- To place a minimum width for `IOPanel` we use `QSizePolicy()` and `setMinimumSize()`

Complete code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Field(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text="0", parent=None):
        super(Field, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setText(text)


class IOPanel(QWidget):
    numbers_of_fields = 4
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(IOPanel, self).__init__(parent=None)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        for _ in range(self.numbers_of_fields):
            w = Field()
            lay.addWidget(w)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(40, 0))
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        self.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)



class Panel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Panel, self).__init__(parent=None)
        lay = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.input = IOPanel()
        self.output = IOPanel()
        self.canvas = QWidget()

        lay.addWidget(self.input, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        lay.addWidget(self.canvas, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(self.output, 0, Qt.AlignRight)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.initUi()
        self.reset_placement()

    def initUi(self):
        panel = Panel(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(panel)
        self.addToolBar(Qt.BottomToolBarArea, QToolBar(self))

    def reset_placement(self):
        g = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()
        self.resize(0.4 * g.width(), 0.4 * g.height())
        self.move(g.center().x() - self.width() / 2, g.center().y() - self.height() / 2)


def main():
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I've managed to restructure my code properly and it now works (and will hopefully continue to work when I add more stuff).